# How to resize a plot (not the window) in R?

Tags: r

Hopefully a simple question for the community tonight: 
I'm creating a boxplot with particularly long xlabels, which are rotated. The issue I'm running in to is that regardless of what plot window size I set using

```
dev.new(width=999, height=999)
```

The plot itself stretches to fill the window,and the x labels are chopped. 
**How do I resize the plot itself, regardless of window size?**
My current plotting code is:

```
boxplot(mean_density~Landscape*category,ylab="Mean density",las=2,data=data1C)
```

The reason the X labels are so long is because of that landscape*category piece.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Its a good idea when asking questions to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with some sample data that we can use for testing possible solutions. But most likely with base graphics you'll just need to increase the margin size in `par()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to MrFlicks quick response I managed to track down the mar() function within par().

```
boxplot(mean_density~Land.Cat,ylab="Mean density",las=2,data=data1C)
```

generated:

[image]

whereas
boxplot(mean_density~Land.Cat,ylab="Mean_density",las=2,par(mar=c(9,4,1,4)),data=data1C)

generates:

[image]

Figured it'd be an easy one:-D thanks for the help!